# Publishing to a Cloud hosted Azure service bus from behind proxy

Tags: c#, azure, proxy

Ive read through the other service bus related questions but cant find a solution so sorry if this is in fact a duplicate.

Im trying to connect and publish to a Cloud hosted Azure Service Bus from behind my workplace's proxy. I understand I need to set the Connectivity mode to http to get the post through the firewall but how do I give the namespaceManager object the credentials and IP required for our proxy server to get the message sent out to the net?

at the moment I have:

```
        ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;

        // Configure Topic Settings
        TopicDescription td = new TopicDescription("TestTopic");
        td.MaxSizeInMegabytes = 5120;
        td.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

        //Establish connection to service bus
        string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up NamespaceManager");
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        Console.WriteLine("NamespaceManager created for " + namespaceManager.Address.ToString());


        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to access topic on " + namespaceManager.Address.ToString());

        //Create a topic
        Console.WriteLine("Creating topic");
        if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists("TestTopic")) {
            namespaceManager.CreateTopic(td);
            Console.WriteLine("Topic created successfully");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Topic already exists");
        }
```

I've seen some examples but none seem to apply any proxy settings to the outgoing requests . Thank you in advance :)

Comment: have you taken a look here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Comment: Hi mike, thank you for pointing me down the config route, which had somehow slipped my mind. For anyone else having proxy issues, I managed to get this working by adding : <system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
   <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="xxxxxxx" bypassonlocal="True" />
  </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>  to my appConfig file

Comment: mike, would give you the props but cant see a way of doing it as you left a comment rather than an answer